# Keras Image Data Generator: fit_generator() argument error

Tags: python, image, keras

For a project on the cifar10 dataset from Keras, I've run into a wall in terms of image augmentation. In short, I've followed the description from the Keras documentation: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/. However, I'm not able to run my code as an argument error occurs on the fit_generator function (see below):

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
/home/nct01/nct01002/new_MAI-DL/lab_1/code_lab1.3.py in <module>()
     86 #trying the dataaugmentation fit function
     87 history = nn.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32),
---> 88                     steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) / 32, epochs=30, validation_sp
lit=0.15)
     89 
     90 #Evaluate the model with test set
```

Here is the code I've used for preparing the data:

```
#Load the CIFAR dataset, already provided by Keras
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

#Check sizes of dataset
print 'Number of train examples', x_train.shape[0]
print 'Size of train examples', x_train.shape[1:]

#Normalize data
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train = x_train / 255
x_test = x_test / 255


#import library for data augmentation
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

#prepare image augmentation
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# apply datagen to training data
datagen.fit(x_train)
```

And here is the code for initializing the training:

```
#trying the dataaugmentation fit function
history = nn.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32),
                    steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) / 32, epochs=30, validation_split=0.15)
```

P.s.: For the project, I'm required to use Keras version 1.1.1

Comment: Can you print these? 1 - shape of x_train //// 2 -  shape of y_train //// 3 - type of y_train //// type of x and y coming from `x,y = next(datagen.flow(...))`

Comment: Isn't `steps_per_epoch` introduced in Keras 2?